# Executing an sql statement into a dataframe and receiving this error ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database

For some reason this line of code isn't working for me anymore on a specific table. And I'm not sure how I'd go about fixing it.

```py
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM "+key+"."+table+"", conn, chunksize=10000)
```

Error I receive:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (74,) + inhomogeneous part.

This used to work, but I've been receiving this error recently

Comment: That SQL looks dangerously open to SQL Injection... I *hope* that those values aren't coming from user input, and that you are, within your python, sanitising the value and (hopefully) confirming that you're referencing a *real* table.

Comment: @ThomA yeah sorry, those values will only be coming from me. And yeah, real table(s). I just tried the same process on a different table and am receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Require bit more information ,but that looks like Numpy giving error. Have you tried  with "dtype=object". To see why you getting tuple like (74,)